# IndexError: Boolean Index did not match indexed array

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, indexing, scalar

I am trying to solve this issue in a specific way. Would love pointers on how to proceed.

I have df1, which is:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Model': ['model1', 'model2', 'model3']})
```

Then there is df2, which is:

```
model1 = pd.DataFrame({'Model' : ['model1', 'model1', 'model1'],
                     'Rule' : ['High', 'Low', 'High'],
                     'Name' : ['A', 'B', 'C']})
model2 = pd.DataFrame({'Model' : ['model2', 'model2', 'model2'],
                     'Rule' : ['Low', 'Low', 'High'],
                     'Name' : ['B', 'D', 'F']})
model3 = pd.DataFrame({'Model' : ['model3', 'model3', 'model3'],
                     'Rule' : ['High', 'High', 'High'],
                     'Name' : ['D', 'E', 'F']})
df2 = [model1, model2, model3]
```

Then there is df3, which is:

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'Name' : ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'],
                     'model1' : [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan,],
                     'High1' : [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan,],
                     'Low1' : [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan,],
                     'model2' : [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan,],
                     'High2' : [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan,],
                     'Low2' : [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan,],
                     'model3' : [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan,],
                     'High3' : [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan,],
                     'Low3' : [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan,]})
```

I want the output to look like this:

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'Name' : ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'],
                     'model1' : ['Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', np.nan, np.nan, np.nan,],
                     'High1' : [0, np.nan, 0, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan,],
                     'Low1' : [np.nan, 0, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan,],
                     'model2' : [np.nan, 'Yes', np.nan, 'Yes', np.nan, 'Yes',],
                     'High2' : [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 0,],
                     'Low2' : [np.nan, 0, np.nan, 0, np.nan, np.nan,],
                     'model3' : [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes',],
                     'High3' : [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 0, 0, 0,],
                     'Low3' : [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan,]})
```

This is my code:

```
for model in df1['Model']:
            col_index = df3.columns.get_loc(model)
            df3.iloc[df3['Name'].isin(df2[model]['Name']), col_index] = 'Yes'
            df3.iloc[df3['Name'].isin(df2[model]['Name']) & (df2[model]['Rule']=='High'), col_index+1] = 0
            df3.iloc[df3['Name'].isin(df2[model]['Name']) & (df2[model]['Rule']=='Low'), col_index+2] = 0
```

This gives me the following error:

```
IndexError: boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 0; dimension is 389 but corresponding boolean dimension is 853
```

I'm assuming this is caused by (df2[model]['Rule']=='High') where 'High' is a scalar.

Note: I want the code to work through this using a for loop as shown in the code above, because it helps with additional stuff i'm doing.

Comment: I edited the question to better explain my problem. The original post did not do that well and did not have reproducible code for the datasets. The edit solves that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are just looking for pivot

```
df3.pivot('Name', 'Property', 'Name').notnull()

Property   colA   colB   colC
Name                         
A          True   True  False
B         False  False   True
C          True  False   True
```

Comment: Can you help me understand what is wrong with my code? I really need to fix the index error and apply my for loop code to a much bigger dataset.